# Avoiding mouse cursor blocking at the end of the window?

Tags: java, processing

I'm working for a simple game. Mouse movement must rotate the view. But when the mouse reaches the edges of the window it freezes and mouseX and mouseY variables no longer increment. How do I make them increment even if they have reached the edge of the window?

I tried with mouseMove() in this way:

```
void draw() {
  currentMouseX = mouseX;
  currentMouseY = mouseY;

  // This is just for keep the mouse cursor at the same position
  robot.mouseMove(800, 500);
}

void mouseMoved() {
  dx = mouseX - currentMouseX;
  dy = mouseY - currentMouseY;
  
  println(dx, dy);
}
```

but I can't get the correct direction. Some help?

Comment: Has been discussed here: https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/global-mouse.html